# MultiIndex and read_table with separate indexes and data

Tags: pandas

I am trying to read a space delimited file with hierarchical indexes in a separate part of a file. This is what I have come up with:

```
import pandas as pd
o = open(doc, 'rU')
for i in o:
    if i.startswith("DATA="):
        meta_ends=o.tell() + 5
        break
dp = pd.read_table(o, delim_whitespace=True, 
  lineterminator='\n', header=None, index_col=None)
```

File looks like this:

```
 META (the exact structure is probably not relevant for this example)
 DATA=1 2 3 4
 5 6 7 9
 10 11 12 13
```

Data has space delimited columns and line break separated rows.

I have created MultiIndexes for rows and columns with `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays`, which I parse separately. This is what I should end up with:

```
                               Column 1                Column 2
Row label 1 Row label 2
Koko maa    1989               2008231.0               4891866.0   
            1990               2036693.0               4924388.0   
Akaa        1989                  6436.0                 15637.0   
            1990                  6548.0                 15775.0   
Alajärvi    1989                  3777.0                 11653.0   
            1990                  3831.0                 11747.0
```

My previous approach was to read the data portion to memory and then create a DataFrame like so:

```
col_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(cols)
row_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(rows)
return pd.DataFrame(data, index=row_index, columns=col_index)
```

With 500Mb+ data and 5M row labels and 50+ columns Pandas reads all available memory (16Gt with swap, which does not work). With read_table, I can save memory by reading the data portion only once.

My question is how to set MultiIndexes for both rows and columns to an existing DataFrame?

Or is there a way to give read_table an external MultiIndex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the column and row index after the fact using

```
df.index = row_index
df.columns = col_index
```

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import io

content = '''\
    176.792 -2.30523 0.430772 32016 1 1 2
    177.042 -1.87729 0.430562 32016 1 1 1
    177.047 -1.54957 0.431853 31136 1 1 1
    177.403 -0.657246 0.432905 31152 1 1 1
'''
df = pd.read_table(io.BytesIO(content), sep='\s+', header=None)
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
          ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = zip(*arrays)
row_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples[:len(df)])
col_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples[:len(df.columns)])
df.index = row_index
df.columns = col_index
print(df)
```

yields

```
             bar                 baz         foo       qux
             one       two       one    two  one  two  one
bar one  176.792 -2.305230  0.430772  32016    1    1    2
    two  177.042 -1.877290  0.430562  32016    1    1    1
baz one  177.047 -1.549570  0.431853  31136    1    1    1
    two  177.403 -0.657246  0.432905  31152    1    1    1
```

Comment: Thank you. This answers my question perfectly. Using this I realised (yet again) that my data is actually delimited only by space and chunked into parts by number of columns. I will create a new question for that.